# How to deal with very s-shaped qq plot in a linear mixed model (lme4 1.0.4)?

Tags: mixed-model, residuals, lme4-nlme, qq-plot

I have a dataset in which I have measured a variable (`diff`) on 38 participants (`sub`) in two different conditions (`cond.lag`). Now I am interested in whether or not the slope of the `position` of the item differs between the two conditions. That is I am interested in whether or not there is an interaction between `cond.lag` and `position` (which I center on 0 prior).

```
require(lme4)
options(contrasts=c('contr.sum', 'contr.poly'))

# read data
dat <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MmNQigRv", colClasses = c(NA, rep("factor", 2), rep("numeric", 2)))
# center position
dat$pos.centered <- scale(dat$position, scale = FALSE)

# fit the model
m1 <- lmer(diff ~ cond.lag * pos.centered + (cond.lag * pos.centered|sub), dat)
print(summary(m1), corr = FALSE)
## [...]
## Fixed effects:
##                          Estimate Std. Error t value
## (Intercept)             0.0819639  0.0121378   6.753
## cond.lag1              -0.0122033  0.0155427  -0.785
## pos.centered            0.0031775  0.0006429   4.942
## cond.lag1:pos.centered -0.0011495  0.0011351  -1.013
```

Although it appears as if I don't find an interaction (only a main effect of the slope of position), I am unsure of wether or not this model makes sense as I find a very unusual (I expect heavy tailed) qq plot:

```
qqnorm(resid(m1))
qqline(resid(m1))
```

[image]

**Questions**:

- Does this model make any sense albeit the seemingly bad behaved residuals?
- What can I do to remove those heavy tails or obtain a better model?

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt, look at the raw data:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(dat,aes(pos.centered,diff,colour=cond.lag))+geom_point()+
    geom_line(aes(group=sub:cond.lag),alpha=0.4)
ggsave("SE_ex.png",width=6,height=4)
```

[image]

(You could also try `colour=sub` and `facet_grid(.~cond.lag)`)

It looks like your problem is the explosion of variance for centered position >5 or so (more variance than expected just from diverging individual lines). I'm not quite sure what to do about it: you could look at the individual curves a bit more and think about whether there's a good (phenomenologically or mechanistically) nonlinear model for these data. It's a bit hard at the moment to combine heteroscedasticity models (which `lme` can do but not `lmer`) with crossed random effects (possible in `lme`, but harder than in `lmer`) in R, but might (??) be possible e.g. in SAS `PROC NLMIXED`, Genstat/AS-REML, AD Model Builder ...

Comment: As I don't seem to have crossed random effects and am no `lme` whizkid, can you give a quick idea of how to build such a heteroscedastic model. Furthermore, would you consider the `qqplot` dramatic enough to abandon the model? (btw, thanks for the response)

Comment: yes, I would be quite worried about the model with this Q-Q plot.  You might be able to use something like `weights=varPower(form=~pos.centered*I(pos.centered>0))` ... ??

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Nevertheless I will keep this question open for some more time, perhaps I can still attract others' attraction.